# Android Studio: Register.Activity.class displays Register.Activity in RED even though code compiles

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

After generating Cloud code and adding this line to MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
```

Android Studio displays  "RegisterActivity" in the color RED.  Hovering yields "Cannot resolve
symbol 'RegisterActivity'

I ignored it, the code runs, but I wonder how to make it not RED and how to fix the "Cannot resolve"... error

thanks
-a

Answer (score 0):

Usually clicking the **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem earlier.

Solution : Add a dependency of your android module(eg : app) with the module which contains the Register activity(eg : app-endpoints).
* Dependancy can be added through module settings or clicking on the "help" popup bulb the comes in the left side of the erroneous code.

Note : Clean and re-build your project after adding dependency injection.